# Windows hosted QEMU Networking

Tags: yocto, qemu

I am trying to get a yocto image working networking on windows QEMU ARM64

I have proven that it works with ubuntu server on ARM following this example
https://gist.github.com/billti/d904fd6124bf6f10ba2c1e3736f0f0f7

so im trying to start the image with the same networking as the example above

```
qemu-system-aarch64 -m 2G -cpu cortex-a57 -M virt -kernel Image-qemuarm64-tt.bin -drive file=tt-qemuarm64-tt.rootfs.ext4 -nographic -append "root=/dev/vda" -device virtio-net-device, netdev=net0 -netdev user,hostfwd=tcp:127.0.0.1:2222-:22,id=net0
```

but i get the below warning and the image wont start

```
WARNING: Image format was not specified for 'tt-qemuarm64-tt.rootfs.ext4' and pr
obing guessed raw.
         Automatically detecting the format is dangerous for raw images, write o
perations on block 0 will be restricted.
         Specify the 'raw' format explicitly to remove the restrictions.
qemu-system-aarch64: netdev=net0: drive with bus=0, unit=0 (index=0) exists
```

anybody know what is the issue above based on the info above

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra space character between `-device virtio-net-device,` and `netdev=net0`. This means that QEMU treats `netdev=net0` as a separate command line argument, which is to say a disk image filename. It then complains because it thinks you've specified an image for the first disk drive in two conflicting ways.

TLDR: remove that extra space.

The warning about 'raw' format is separate; you can silence it by changing your `-drive` option to explicitly tell QEMU your disk is a raw image, with `-drive file=whatever,format=raw`.

Comment: fixed the space and the images now starts. also the suggestion fixed the warning as well. thank you